# Linq Query and Expected Results -- Distinct Field

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a nested `linq` to `sql` query that is used to populate a `treeview`.  The first select (`Title` Field) when being bound to the `treeview` is showing all of the `Titles` correctly, but if there is multiple occurences I want it to show up once.  How can I solve this?

I tried

```
              }).Distinct().OrderBy(c => c.LineNumber)

}).Distinct();
```

Full Query

```
var results =
    (from d in mContext.Docs
     orderby d.Title ascending
     join b in mContext.Base on d.DocId equals b.DocId
     join h in mContext.ViewDocItems on b.BaseId equals h.BaseId
     where h.ItemId == mGuid
     select new
     {
         Id = d.DocId, 
         Title = d.Title, 
         ClassId = d.ClassId,
         BaseHis =
             (from c in d.Base

             select new BaseHistory()
             {
                 BaseId = c.BaseId,
                 Name = c.Title,
                 BaseFinal = c.Final.Value,
                 LineNumber = c.LineNumber.Value
                 ItemId = h.ItemId
             }).Distinct().OrderBy(c => c.LineNumber)
    });

foreach(var r in results)
{
    var hist = new DocHistory() 
    {
        Id = r.Id,
        Title = r.Title,
        ClassId = r.ClassId;
    };
    foreach(var h in r.BaseHis)
    {
        hist.BaseHis.Add(h);
    }

    mHistory.Add(hist); 
}
```

Comment: You've said what you tried, but not what happened.

Comment: Nothing changed after adding the second distinct().  The results are the same.  The Titles are showing correctly, I just want to show one of each Title even if there are multiple occurences of the same Title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `Distinct()` by

```
.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
```

That means that you do a grouping on `Name` (i.e. `Title`) and then take the first element of each group.

Distinct does not work, because, translated to SQL it filters out all records with unique values for *each* value of `BaseId`, `Title`, etc.